Send a request from Server-Side Component with httpOnly cookies NextJS
everybody. I am writing my first application on Nextjs. I have already written some server with JWT tokens (httpOnly!). Here is an example of their application:
// main.ts

import { NestFactory } from "@nestjs/core";
import { AppModule } from "./app.module";
import * as cors from "cors";
import * as cookieParser from "cookie-parser";

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.setGlobalPrefix("api");
  app.use(
    cors({
      origin: "http://localhost:3000",
      credentials: true
    })
  );
  app.use(cookieParser());
  await app.listen(process.env.SERVER_PORT ? +process.env.SERVER_PORT : 5000);
}
bootstrap();


// auth.controller.ts

setTokensInCookie(response: Response, accessToken: IToken, refreshToken: IToken) {
    response.cookie(Tokens.ACCESS_TOKEN, accessToken.token, {
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: !isNaN(+accessToken.expiresIn) ? +accessToken.expiresIn : 1000 * 60 * 15 // 15 minutes
    });

    response.cookie(Tokens.REFRESH_TOKEN, refreshToken.token, {
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: !isNaN(+refreshToken.expiresIn)
        ? +refreshToken.expiresIn
        : 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 // 7 days
    });
  }

There is a Server-Side Component that executes a request to get a list of users:
// friends/page.ts

import FriendsPage from "@/src/components/screens/Friends/page";
import UserService from "@/src/services/user";

async function Friends() {
  const allUsers = await await customFetch<IFriendsPageUser[]>(this.url, {
      cache: "no-cache"
    });
  return <FriendsPage users={allUsers} />;
}

export default Friends;

// customFetch.ts

const baseApiUrl = "http://localhost:8080/api";

export async function customFetch<ResponseType = Response>(
  url: string,
  options?: RequestInit
) {
  const response = await fetch(`${baseApiUrl}/${url}`, {
    credentials: "include",
    headers: {
      ...options?.headers,
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    ...options
  });

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
  }

  const contentLength = response.headers.get("Content-Length");

  if (!contentLength || +contentLength === 0) return response;
  return response.json() as ResponseType;
}

I want to validate the request from the client by getting the user from it via decode accessToken:
// user.contoller.ts

@Get()
@UseGuards(AuthGuard)
  findAll(@Req() req: RequestWithUser) {
    return this.userService.findAll(req.user.id);
  }

// auth.guard.ts

import { Injectable, CanActivate, ExecutionContext } from "@nestjs/common";
import { verify } from "jsonwebtoken";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { Tokens } from "../enums/tokens.enum";

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate(
    context: ExecutionContext
  ): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const accessToken = request.cookies[Tokens.ACCESS_TOKEN] as string;
    console.log("cookies:", request.cookies);

    if (!accessToken) {
      return false;
    }

    const [bearer, token] = accessToken.split(" ");

    if (bearer !== "Bearer" || !token) {
      console.log("bearer !== Bearer || !token");
      return false;
    }

    try {
      const decoded = verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY);
      request.user = decoded;
      return true;
    } catch (error) {
      return false;
    }
  }
}

Question: why is it coming to the server WITHOUT httpOnly cookies? And in general, is it possible to send a request from Server-Side Component with httpOnly cookies in Nextjs?
